# can i get primary key value and extension after inserting in database using triggers in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

Well, let me explain this as simple as possible, basically i have a table doc_info, which stores information regarding uploaded files; like file name, date created, uploaded by etc;

what i want is to create an INSERT trigger on this table, which will get two things, the primary key ID of this newly inserted row and the extension of the uploaded filename which will be in the document name; and concatenate them and update that same row, with this concatenated value

Example,
If someone uploads "document.docx", then ID will be auto generated as x and document name will be document.docx, thus the value to store will be "x.docx" using update on that same row.

I am new to this MySQL, and have little knowledge if operations like this can be performed with MySQL.

Comment: Typically SQL is not going to be your best tool to do that type of string manipulation. You can do it, but it will be clunky. It would likely be more efficient and easier to either return the row id and do another insert, or simply build the string you need upon select later.

Comment: Well this was already done by me easily in PHP but my supervisor is not happy and want this done with trigger, so will appreciate if you mentioned the clunky part. :p

Comment: PHP handles string manipulation much better than SQL and triggers could be problematic in this instance.

Comment: well said the same thing to my supervisor but he is not listening wants this with triggers so what can i do, dont have the authority to make him change his mind.

Comment: In that case then yes it can be done. The hard part will be splicing the file name string reliably. I was hoping to save you some trouble, so my apologies. I don't have MySQL in front of me at the moment so I can't test the syntax.

Comment: during some research here and on the net i was able to get the auto ID but the extension part is still not coming to me, and not available anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement such action within db you should create two triggers: after insert and on update. They should be like this one

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER changeProperty AFTER INSERT ON doc_info
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE doc_info SET doc_info.someProperty = CONCAT(doc_info.id, doc_info.extension) WHERE doc_info.id = NEW.id;
  END;
|
```

You can calculate extension on you file name by following expression: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(doc_id.fileName, '.', -1);`

Comment: thanx for this, but could you please tell me how to put value from that substring function into variable also, cz i dont have doc_info.extension, if i had i would have done it already; i dont know much about triggers and its still giving me errors

Comment: Well its not done, but i think this is the right one. it is giving me this error:
"Can't update table 'doc_info' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."

Comment: If MySQL giving this error you may try this one instead of `UPDATE...`:
    `NEW.someProperty = CONCAT(NEW.id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.fileName, '.', -1));`